# How do I convert Clamped<Vec<u8>> to Clamped<&mut [u8]> with Rust and web-sys?

Tags: rust, webassembly, wasm-bindgen

I am manipulating pixel data using Rust and WebAssembly, and am struggling to create new ImageData with the manipulated pixels.

When I get my [`ImageData`](https://rustwasm.github.io/wasm-bindgen/api/web_sys/struct.ImageData.html)'s data, it returns a [`Clamped<Vec<u8>>`](https://rustwasm.github.io/wasm-bindgen/api/wasm_bindgen/struct.Clamped.html)

```
   fn get_buffer_image_data(&self) -> Clamped<Vec<u8>> {
    let image_data = match self.buffer_ctx.get_image_data(0.0, 0.0, 640.0, 480.0) {
        Ok(d) => d,
        Err(_err) => panic!("failed to fetch buffer image data")
    };
    
    image_data.data()
}
```

I manipulate the pixel data in another function, and then attempt to create new ImageData with these manipulated pixels. The problem is that I can only create new ImageData with [Clamped<&mut [u8]>](https://rustwasm.github.io/wasm-bindgen/api/web_sys/struct.ImageData.html#method.new_with_u8_clamped_array_and_sh)

```
    fn create_image_data(&self, data: Clamped<Vec<u8>>) {
        let imageData = ImageData::new_with_u8_clamped_array_and_sh(data, 640, 480);
    }
```

However, the error I receive is:

```
mismatched types

expected `&mut [u8]`, found struct `std::vec::Vec`

note: expected struct `wasm_bindgen::Clamped<&mut [u8]>`
         found struct `wasm_bindgen::Clamped<std::vec::Vec<u8>>`
```

I think I need to convert one type to another. How do I convert efficiently? I have been trying this for a while and I am stuck. The only solution I have is to send the entire Uint8ClampedArray to wasm from my JS. Here is a code example you can use. Note, if you clone this repo please checkout the branch `problem` https://github.com/Fallenstedt/rotated-pixels/blob/problem/src/pixel_rotator.rs#L42-L44

Comment: `let x: &[u8] = &data.0[..]`

Comment: `Clamped` internals are public, it's just a wrapper, so you can do the conversion yourself

Comment: Ah this is right. There is 'as_mut_slice' available to me. Rust is fairly new to me. 

Thank you! 
https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.as_mut_slice

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look at the source code for [`Clamped`](https://rustwasm.github.io/wasm-bindgen/api/src/wasm_bindgen/lib.rs.html#1159), you'll see that it is just a wrapper around `T`.

```rust
pub struct Clamped<T>(pub T);
```

Because the inner `T` is public, you can perform any operations on it, such as converting a `Vec` to a slice:

```rust
let slice_data: &mut [u8] = &mut data.0[..];
```

You can then wrap `slice_data` in a new instance of `Clamped`, and pass it to `ImageData`:

```rust
fn create_image_data(&self, data: Clamped<Vec<u8>>) {
  let slice_data = Clamped(&mut data.0[..]);
  let imageData = ImageData::new_with_u8_clamped_array_and_sh(slice_data, 640, 480);
}
```